# check child the given class in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to check the parent div 'tabs' has the child with class 'nav-justified' in jquery .In my html block 'nav-justified' class is exist but shows 'class not exit' due to condition failed.how to check parent div 'tabs ' has the child 'nav-justified' with given class name.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
if($('#tabs').children().hasClass('nav-justified'))
{
alert('helloexist');
}else{
alert('class not exist');}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tabs">
 <div class="view view-tabs view-id-tabs view-display-id-block view-dom-id-f25d21847449ac13dbfa35f1bbd014d7">
  <div class="view-content">
   <ul class="nav  nav-justified tabs-section">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try `$('#tabs').find(".nav-justified").length`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the change that I mentioned in comment above. You should find by `class` and check the `length`:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  if ($('#tabs').find('.nav-justified').length) {
    alert('helloexist');
  } else {
    alert('class not exist');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tabs">
  <div class="view view-tabs view-id-tabs view-display-id-block view-dom-id-f25d21847449ac13dbfa35f1bbd014d7">
    <div class="view-content">
      <ul class="nav  nav-justified tabs-section">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS selectors to select specific element, then check the length of the collection:

```js
if ($("#tabs .nav-justified").length) {
  alert("Exist");
} else {
  alert("The class is not exist");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tabs">
  <div class="view view-tabs view-id-tabs view-display-id-block view-dom-id-f25d21847449ac13dbfa35f1bbd014d7">
    <div class="view-content">
      <ul class="nav  nav-justified tabs-section">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```